# Basic Olympiad number theory problem about prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm learning a basic lesson of number theory and get stuck with this :

Find all positive integers $n$ and prime numbers $p$ such that $n^p+3^p$ is a perfect square.

I found that if $p \ge 3$, then $n$ is in the form $4k+1$ but I'm not sure if I am on the right way. Any help would be welcome:). Thank you.

Comment: I do not know if this helps but going modulo $p$ gives that $n+3$ is a perfect square modulo $p$ whenever $p \geq 3$

Comment: Isn't "basic" and "Olympiad" a bit of a contradiction? :-)

Comment: @joriki, no, it isn't. However, this one does not look basic to me.

Comment: Hmm just deleted my answer after I realised all I had proved was that $n$ is of the form $4k+1$ and the square number must be even. This one is not basic.

Comment: A useful fact: if $p$ is prime and $gcd(a,b)=1$, then $gcd(\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b},a+b)$ divides $p$. So we can consider the case where 3 divides n, and separately, $n+3=p^tA^2$ and $n^p+3^p=(n+3)p^tB^2$, where $t \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: For $p=2$, the only solution is $3^2+4^2=5^2$. I think, for $p>3$, there are no solutions, but I do not have a proof yet. The only solution seems to be $n=4,p=2$